# Cross-platform Library

Tags: c, cross-platform, static-libraries

Basically, I want to seperate some common functionality from existing projects into a seperate library project, but also allow a project to remain cross-platform when I include this library.

I should clarify that when I say "cross-platform" I'm primarily concerned with compiling for multiple CPU architectures (x86/x86_64/ARM).

I have a few useful functions which I use across many of my software projects. So I decided that it was bad practice to keep copying these source code files between projects, and that I should create a seperate library project from them.

I decided that a static library would suit my needs better than a shared library. However, it occurred to me that the static library would be plaform dependent, and by including it with my projects that would cause these projects to also be platform dependent. This is clearly a disadvantage over including the source code itself.

Two possible solutions occur to me:

1. Include a static library compiled for each platform.
2. Continue to include the source code.

I do have reservations about both of the above options. Option 1 seems overly complex/wasteful. Option 2 seems like bad practice, as it's possible for the "library" to be modified per project and become out-of-sync; especially if the library source code is stored in the same directory as all the other project source code.

I'd be really grateful for any suggestions on how to overcome this problem, or information on how anyone else has previously overcome this problem?

Comment: You have multiple *platforms*. Building a common library, shared or static, makes little difference. Just like your project code, your common library must be built for each platform as well. There is no escaping that (barring something like a C++ template header-only library, which has no platform-dependent image since it is introduced during compilation of the client code).

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that. As I said, I could have the static library pre-compiled for different platforms. However, I was wondering if anyone could recommend a neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt the standard approach of open source project (even if your project is not open source). There would be one central point where one can obtain the source code, presumably under revision control (subversion, git...). Anyone who wishes to use the library should check out the source code, compile it (a Makefile or something similar should be included), and then they are all set. If someone needs to change something in the library, they do so, test their changes, and send you a patch so that you can apply the change to the project (or not, depending on your opinion on the patch).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess this would be more suitable with a shared object? Honestly, I was trying to keep users from having to perform multiple `make`, `make install`.

Comment: In that case, you can provide binaries. Of course this means you have to compile for several platforms each time, but this can be automated. Building for x86 on an x86-64 machine is usually easy, you will just need a 32-bit toolchain. To generate the ARM binary, you could have an ARM emulator with a virtual machine in which you have a script that fetches the source code, compiles, gives you back the binary (or an error message, if you are unlucky, but then you would have needed to fix it anyway).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate what your saying, and know this is how some projects work. But it seems unnecessarily complex and somewhat wasteful?

Comment: This completely depends on the use case. Why do you want to keep users from having to build your library ? Supposing your source code unpacks in a folder named `mylib`, all they have to do is copy this folder into their source tree and add to their Makefile something like `cd mylib && make`, exactly once in the life of their project. Is it really that much of an effort ?

Comment: Sorry, I think we confused the term "user"; I was referring to an end user. So, if I were to adopt this model, and copy `mylib` into the source tree. Could you elaborate on how you would organise the parent project's source tree (directory structure)?

Comment: The end users would never need to compile anything anymore than before and I don't think it would change anything at all to the parent project's source tree. All that changes is 1) the developers need to add `#include mylib/header.h`, 2) the build process needs to do `cd mylib && make`, 3) the linking phase needs to know that the library is to be added into the resulting executable.

Comment: OK. So you would just copy the whole `mylib` source tree into the root of the parent project's source tree?

Comment: Yes. Also, this discussion is becoming too long for StackOverflow; if you need further answers, you should ask a new question. Maybe take time to think about it, try something, and come back if needed.